# Structure parameter corrupted on function call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86, function-calls

I'm having trouble tracking down the cause of strange behavior in passing a structure as a parameter.

The structure in question, structFoo, has the following declaration:

```
typedef struct _structFoo {
    int id;
    BSTR szDescription;
    VARIANT vData;
    BOOL bTransient;
} structFoo;
```

I have two modules, A and B. Module A calls B::foo( int id, uint filter, structFoo sF ). In A, before the call, the structFoo structure is properly formed and filled with valid data. However, once the function call to B::foo() is made, the structFoo parameter has garbage data in it. Upon further examination, it turns out that the address of the copied struct is put into the id field, and the szDescription points to the most recently used string. The other parameters are correct after the function call.

I'm not sure the reason for this misalignment, or whatever is happening, but it appears to me that up until the function call is made, everything is in its proper place. Here's the disassembly leading up to the function call:

```
0000000006003211  lea         rdi,[rsp+230h] 
0000000006003219  lea         rsi,[sAttPairId] 
0000000006003221  mov         ecx,30h 
0000000006003226  rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi] 
0000000006003228  mov         rax,qword ptr [piConstruct] 
0000000006003230  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax] 
0000000006003233  lea         r9,[rsp+230h] 
000000000600323B  mov         r8d,800h 
0000000006003241  mov         edx,dword ptr [iHighNodeId] 
0000000006003248  mov         rcx,qword ptr [piConstruct] 
0000000006003250  call        qword ptr [rax+60h]
```

And here is the disassembly after the function call:

```
0000000004B72470  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],r9 
0000000004B72475  mov         dword ptr [rsp+18h],r8d 
0000000004B7247A  mov         dword ptr [rsp+10h],edx 
0000000004B7247E  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx 
0000000004B72483  push        rsi  
0000000004B72484  push        rdi  
0000000004B72485  sub         rsp,0A8h 
0000000004B7248C  mov         rdi,rsp 
0000000004B7248F  mov         rcx,2Ah 
0000000004B72499  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
0000000004B7249E  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi] 
0000000004B724A0  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h] 
0000000004B724A8  mov         qword ptr [rsp+90h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh
```

After the `sub rsp, 0A8h` the parameters are all set with data, but the sF parameter has the address of the correct structFoo information in its id field, rather than using this address as its own pointer. Any guidance on resolving this is greatly appreciated.

As a side note, changing B::foo() to take the address of the struct rather than the struct itself is unfortunately not an option. A great deal of legacy code relies on this function that I do not have the authority to change.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code for `B::foo( int id, uint filter, structFoo sF )` ?

Comment: This may be a silly question but. Why do you have `typedef struct` ?

Comment: there is **no need** to declare structs as `typedef struct TAG_NAME {}  REAL_NAME;` in C++.  Just do `struct REAL_NAME {};`

Comment: @ahenderson:  This is typically a hold-over from C.

Comment: @ahenderson I cannot, unfortunately it is proprietary. However, it should not be relevant to this issue, as the problem occurs before any of the body of  `B::foo()` is executed

Comment: @JohnDibling I realize that it's C-style, but I believe it is functionally the same once it's compiled

Comment: Are the two modules compiled with identical compiler arguments?  Perhaps they are each being compiled with a different alignment, and so the physical layout of the struct is different within each module?

Comment: Just guess: maybe you've got an ODR violation (eg. due to some macro that affects the struct definition)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, modules `A` and `B` are compiled with different calling conventions. Module `A` passes structures to functions by reference/pointer, while module `B` expects to receive structures on the stack, by value.

There might be a modifier in `B`'s header file, like so:

```
__weird_call void B::foo( int id, uint filter, structFoo sF );
```

Maybe the compiler of module `A` doesn't understand it, or some other header-file defines it out (`#define __weird_call /* nothing */`), or something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this page while looking for answer to a similar problem I faced.
Although I could not find answer on the internet, sharing the experience of debugging.

The below structure was passed by reference from one function to other, and the receiver would find that the received data was unexpected:

```
typedef struct
{
    char time_st[30];
    char pipe_no;
    float loss;
    float power[4];
    int   mode;
    int   count;
}Parameters;
```

Another finding was that if I define the receiver function in the same file as caller function, the problem would disappear.

Upon debugging, the root cause was found to be spaghetti use of "#pragma pack" in legacy .h files in the system causing problems of structure packing -- due to inclusion of several legacy header files in the .c file of the caller function, the structure was packed, but in the .c file of the receiver function (which was written new during the project activity), the structure was treated as unpacked.

Resolution: add sufficient padding to make the structure word aligned

```
typedef struct
{
    char time_st[30];
    char pad;
    char pipe_no;
    float loss;
    float power[4];
    int   mode;
    int   count;
}Parameters;
```