# How to declare structures in C to avoid structure corruption?

Tags: c, struct, padding, packing

I have a similar problem like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000798/structure-parameter-corrupted-on-function-call) and my problem was solved similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24545343/2641387) but I can't understand what caused this issue.
I have three structures `File`, `Line` and `Buffer` declared in `app.h`.

```
typedef struct File {
    FILE *fs;
    char *path;
    size_t size;
} File;

typedef struct Line Line;
struct Line {
    char *text;
    size_t len;
    size_t line_no;
    Line *next;
    Line *prev;
};

typedef struct Buffer {
    int id;
    File file;
    Line *first;
    Line *last;
    Line *current;
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
    int visual_x;
    bool modified;
} Buffer;
```

The `Makefile` is as follow:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g
LDFLAGS = 
LDLIBS = -lcurses
OBJECTS = app.o io.o global.o move.o winio.o utils.o

all: app

app: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

%.o: %.c proto.h app.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm app
    -rm *.o
```

There is a global pointer for `Buffer` structure: `extern Buffer *buffer` declared in `proto.h` and defined in `global.c` and `*buffer` is dynamically allocated in `io.c`. There are several functions in `io.c` that work with `*buffer`. I moved `show_buffer()` function of `io.c` to another module like `winio.c`

```
void show_buffer()
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    Line *it;

    for (it = buffer->first; it != NULL && i < (LINES - STATBAR_HEIGHT);
            it = it->next, i++) {
        for (j = 0; it->text[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            waddch(mainwin, it->text[j]);
        }

    }
}
```

and I also removed `size` member of `File` structure. Then `show_buffer()` in `winio.c` didn't work anymore. I found out that `show_buffer()` was working with corrupted `buffer->first` pointer. I recompiled every module but didn't work.

*The problem solved when I added `size` member of `File` structure again.* I also figured out that if I move `show_buffer()` back to `io.c`, the problem would be solved. I suspect structure padding might cause the problem.

My question is what caused the problem and how to avoid it.

#### Resolution

A precompiled header was causing problems because it was not being recompiled.

Comment: Did you try fully recompiling (e.g., `make clean && make` in Linux)?

Comment: You''ll really need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Global variables are bad news at the best of times.  There are a lot of moving parts here (`app.h`, `proto.h`, `gobal.c` [sic], `io.c`, `winio.c` at minimum).  Are you sure you recompiled everything properly?  One way to get corruption is to recompile some but not all files.  There are many pointers around; are they all properly initialized before use.  Frankly, this is abstruse enough to be unanswerable.  You'd have to show an MCVE (as mentioned previously), but that is not going to be a trivial proposition.

Comment: @rlbond Yes I recompiled every module

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes all of the pointers properly initialized. As I mentioned in my post, the problem solved by either moving `show_buffer()` back to its original module or re-adding `size` member of `File` struc. This problem is reproducible.

Comment: It is not a matter of `struct` declaration. You probably have some memory corruption. Use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and `gdb`

Comment: As noted in the answer, you need to check for multiple definitions of the struct and make sure you're including the right header in every c file that uses the structure.  Without seeing all of the files and knowing the details of how you're compiling the program I'm afraid you're not going to get more than advice on what the right thing to do is or guesses.

Comment: No; it is not reproducible by us.  We don't have, and probably cannot have, all your code (there's too much of it).  What you've shown in the question does not allow us to reproduce the problem.  Moving a function between source files does not cause corruption — there is something else going on which you've not tracked down yet.  Have you run with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) yet?  You're doing lots of linked list and other work that must involve dynamic memory allocation; `valgrind` will point out if you are abusing dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I ran the program with `valgrind` and no error was reported.

Comment: My curiosity is piqued.  If you want, send me an archive of the code via email — see my profile.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I was creating your requested archive code, I found the cause of the problem. you can check my answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question in the hope that it will be useful for others. While I was investigating the cause of the problem, I stumbled upon a **precompiled header** file `app.h.gch` in the working directory. I suspect that in the previous versions of my `Makefile`, I had passed `app.h` to the compiler without being aware of it. Unfortunately there was no rule in the `Makefile` to remove precompiled headers. When I removed `app.h.gch` and recompiled the whole project, everything got back to normal.

Comment: I'm glad you got it resolved.  I would not have guessed that precompiled headers would be the cause of the trouble.  I tried to use them a few years ago and wasn't really successful, and compilation times weren't enough of a pain for the putative benefit to be worth chasing.

Answer (score 4):

Structure definitions are compile-time data.  Once a source file is compiled, the `struct` layouts that the resulting binary components will assume is fixed.  If you fail to ensure that all components of your system that work with a given `struct` type have the same idea of that type's layout (as described below), then it can easily lead to data corruption.  You are lucky that in your case the corruption was so easy to recognize.

Your `struct` definition should appear in a header file (only), and every source file that relies on it should `#include` that header.  If ever you modify the `struct`'s structure by adding or removing a member, by changing a member's type, or by reordering members, all source files that rely on the header must be recompiled.  (Any halfway-decent build system will help you accomplish that pretty easily.)

You can somewhat insulate yourself from such issues by working with pointers to `struct` types instead of with the `struct`s themselves, but that's helpful only until you need to dereference the pointers.

Comment: This answer is probably the best of the lot.